# How to fetch more than one column value from oracle select query to shell variable

Tags: shell, oracle11g, multiple-columns

I am trying to fetch a row with more than one column value to different shell variables. Infact I found that at a time all the column values can be stored to single shell variable. But how can I put those column values to seperate shell variables. Below is an example I am trying for time being

```
function sqlQuery {
sqlplus -S shiyas/********* <<'EOF'
set heading OFF termout ON trimout ON feedback OFF
set pagesize 0
SELECT name,open_mode from v$database;
EOF
}
OUTPUT="$( sqlQuery )"
echo $OUTPUT
```

Here I am getting the output as

```
ORCL READ WRITE
```

But my requirement is column values ORCL, READ WRITE should get assigned to different shell variable.

I tried the below of parsing.

```
echo "$OUTPUT" | while read name open_mode
```

but it was throwing unexpected end of file error.

```
-bash-3.2$ sh call_sql_col_val_1.sh
ORCL READ WRITE
call_sql_col_val_1.sh: line 18: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Please let me know what concept I can use to fetch a single row column values to different shell variables.

Comment: Hi

  Can I get an update.

Thanks

Comment: There you go. BTW this isn't really a ticketing system so be a bro and don't update your own questions asking for updates.

Answer (score 0):

I do this via `eval` myself:

```
oracle@******:/*****> cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
function sqlQuery {
sqlplus -S / as sysdba <<'EOF'
set heading OFF termout ON trimout ON feedback OFF
set pagesize 0
SELECT name,open_mode from v$database;
EOF
}
eval x=(`sqlQuery`)
NAME=${x[0]}
OPEN_MODE="${x[1]} ${x[2]}"
echo NAME IS $NAME
echo OPEN_MODE IS $OPEN_MODE
```

So we are running the same function you have above, passing it into `x` and running it through `eval` to handle the delimitation. Then you have an array and call call is as such: `x[0]` for the first item, for example.
Output is:

```
oracle@******:/******> sh test.sh
NAME IS ******
OPEN_MODE IS READ WRITE
```